# ASP.NET global resources issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, app-globalresources

I got an issue which already cost me some evenings to resolve. 
I migrated a ASP.NET Web Project to a Web Application.

My main issue are the .resx files below App_GlobalResources. 
Let's say that I have MyStrings.resx (= default culture) and MyStrings.en.resx (yes, english is not my default).

If I create the files in the solution in Solution Explorer with "Add...", I am getting the following settings: 
* Build Action: Content
* Custom Tool: GlobalResourceProxyGenerator

I would guess that the default setting is fine for most cases but I already have two issues with that:
a) If I leave the Build Action as "Content", I will get a MissingManifestResourceException when using ResourceManager.GetString in code. Solution: Change it to "EmbeddedResource". 
b) The GlobalResourceProxyGenerator seems to missing on my computer. If I choose "Run Custom Tool" on the .resx I get the error message "Cannot find custom tool '...' on this system. Great. Solution: Change it to "PublicResXFileCodeGenerator". This works.

Now, if I leave the setting at PublicResXFileCodeGenerator, everything compiles but when I run the solution (IIS and VS Express 2013 for Web) I get the friendly message that I got "Resources.MyStrings" both in MyWebSite.dll and in App_GlobalResources.dll.

OK, I change the Custom Tool to "ResXFileCodeGenerator". Now, everything's working fine. 
I am now deploying the solution to the webserver. There I get CS0122: Resources.MyStrings is inaccessible due to its protection level.
That's probably due to it's "internal" declaration.

By now I am completely lost. Any help to clean up the situation?

Environment:
IIS locally and online 
VS Express 2013 for Web
Two languages. 
For both the settings are: 
Build Action: Embedded Resource
Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy
Custom Tool: ResXfileCodeGenerator
Custom Tool Namespace: Resources

For the generated designer files (only default language) the settings are: 
Build Action: Compile
Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

Any help is appreciated

Comment: What;s the problem to make the generated resource file to be Public ? Open the .resx. file with the designer and make it public.

Comment: If I do that, the "Custom Tool" is changed to PublicResXFileCodeGenerator. If I do that, I get the issue that the code is defined in two locations.

Comment: I would be interested to learn why someone rated the topic as -1. Is it unclear? Missing research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't really find the source of my troubles, but I found a good workaround. The core problem was probably that the Resources.MyStrings class was present both in the MyWebsite.dll and in the App_GlobalResoures.dll. I didn't find out what the intended settings are to make sure that you get it only once.

My solution: I created a "Resources" folder, copied all my .resx files over and deleted App_GlobalResources. 
Works great also with different languages.

Why is there an "App_Globalresources" folder at all?